# Full-screen layout on top of flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to implement a full-height layout for complex app, which can contain huge tree of components. It should work the following way: The parent `div` has the following style:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

Some child component should have style `flex-grow: 1` to fill all accessible space. But child component which should stretch can have its own footer, which has to stick to the bottom. For that purpose I wrap this child component in container with the following class:

```
.fullh {
  flex-grow: 1;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

`flex-grow` style tells its parent what this component has to fill all free space, and rest styles for its children. It sounds reasonable, at least for me, but I've faced with a problem. I've simplified my code as much as possible to quite simple example, there a problem is still appearing.

https://jsfiddle.net/DonTomato/vqp9wLx8/80/

In case table has few rows all works as expected:

[image]

In case a table contains more rows and it doesn't fit his place, `scoll-container` block shouldn't change his size and scroll should be appeared. Like on this picture:

[image]

But that I get in reality:

[image]

Can anyone explain the reason? And to fix that?

Comment: min-height:0 to .fullh

Comment: works! But why?

Comment: read the duplicate for the detail